# How is good the practis to compare arguments of function with it's names in Python?

Tags: python, function, pycharm

I've made example functions, I know that i will use meta_function only with arguments `sum` and `mult`

```
def sum(a, b):
    return a + b

def mult(a, b):
    return a*b

def meta_function(function):
    if function == sum:
        c = 1
        print('SUM')
    elif function == mult:
        c = 2
        print("MULT")
    print(c)
    
meta_function(sum)
meta_function(mult)
```

Output:

```
SUM
1
MULT
2
```

PyCharm informing me that `Local variable might be referenced before assignment`. I know, if some other arguments will be taken except `sum` and `mult`, this will lead to error. What is the best practice to handle this sophisticated issue? Try - except? Am I use wright way to take another functions in meta_function?

Comment: That's hard to answer because you are doing nothing useful in the conditional blocks. Are you trying to do something like `def meta_function(func, *args, **kwargs): return func(*args, **kwargs)`?

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm warns you because if the function isn't `sum` or `mult`, your code will crash.

You need to define `c` at the top, just in case, or add an `else` statement.

```py
# I changed the name of sum_ in order to avoid shadowing with
# the python built-in function sum()
def sum_(a, b):
    return a + b


def mult(a, b):
    return a * b


def meta_function(function):
    c = 0  # if function isn't sum or mult, at least c exist
    # here, "is" is better then "=="
    if function is sum_:
        c = 1
        print('SUM')
    # here, "is" is better then "=="
    elif function is mult:
        c = 2
        print("MULT")
    # Or you can do the else, but since you don't do anything in it,
    # the best solution is to define a base state of c
    # else:
    #   c = 0
    print(c)


meta_function(sum_)
meta_function(mult)
```

Here is a better solution in my opinion, in order to prevent changing the core of `meta_function()` if you want to add more functions:

```py
def sum_(a, b):
    return a + b


def mult(a, b):
    return a * b

function_switch = {
    sum_: ('SUM', 1),
    mult: ('MULT', 2),
}

def meta_function(function):
    function_res = function_switch.get(function)
    if function_res is None:
        print(0)
        return

    print(function_res[0])
    print(function_res[1])


meta_function(sum_)
meta_function(mult)
```

In Python 3.9, you can do:

```py
def meta_function(function):
    if (function_res := function_switch.get(function)) is None:
        print(0)
        return

    print(function_res[0])
    print(function_res[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning is shown because if both cases are not happened, then variable `c` will be not defined and print fill fail. The variable must be defined in the current scope.

It is better to make a generic function, executes the function and returns desired values. I've refactored your function as taking callable function and parameters for given function. Executes given callable and return some string that is built with return results.

```py
def sum(a, b):
    return a + b

def mult(a, b):
    return a*b

def meta_function(func, *args):
    # initialize default variables
    c: int = None
    return_str: str = None

    # try execute given callable `func`
    try:
        # execute
        c = func(*args)

        # build some result string and assign
        return_str = f"Function:{func.__name__}, Args: {args}, Result: {c}"
    except Exception as exp:
        # build result string for failed functions
        return_str = f"Error calling given function `{func.__name__}` with params: {params}"

    return return_str

def incompatible_func(x, y, z):  # takes three parameters, will fail
    return x + y * z

params = (1,2)
rslt = meta_function(sum, *params)
print(rslt)
rslt = meta_function(mult, *params)
print(rslt)
rslt = meta_function(incompatible_func, *params)
print(rslt)
```

And the output is:

```
Function:sum, Args: (1, 2), Result: 3
Function:mult, Args: (1, 2), Result: 2
Error calling given function `incompatible_func` with params: (1, 2)
```